# Getting SQL records sharing same keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table for article keywords:

```
id INT 
keyword VARCHAR
```

And I have an article id, let's say 13. This article has 4 keywords in this table. 
I'm trying to get other articles where they share 2 or more keywords.

I can get a list of articles having same keywords with my original article with this query:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE keyword IN (SELECT keyword FROM table WHERE id=13)
```

But this only gives me a list of all articles sharing at least one keyword... But I need articles sharing 2 or more keywords, preferably ordered descending by the most occurrences...

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @original_id int = 13

SELECT
  id,
  COUNT(*) c
FROM keywords k1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT keyword
  FROM keywords
  WHERE id = @original_id
) k2 ON (k1.keyword = k2.keyword)
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY c DESC, id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
     , Count(*) As number_of_keywords
FROM   articles
 INNER
  JOIN keywords
    ON keywords.keyword = articles.keyword
GROUP
    BY id
HAVING Count(*) >= 2
```

Comment: First of all, we don't have to include articles tables in this formula. Keywords table has all the information I need, id and keyword...

And also, articles table doesn't have keywords, they're all in keywords table...